# rails 4 -- concatenate fields in collection_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, html-select

I'm working on learning Rails 4 via several tutorials, and building a demo app.

I have a table called `players` that links to a `team` table. The team has many players, a player has only one team. So I'm using a `collection_select` tag to pull the team data into the player form.

It looks like this:

```
<%= collection_select :player, :team_id, Team.find(:all), :id, :name, options ={:prompt => "Select a team"} %>
```

This works fine-- but I'd like to have the format look like "Team Name: Team City"-- I can't figure out how to concatenate the `:name` and `:city` values in the tag however. Is this possible?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Create a method in your `Team` model like the following one

```
  def name_with_city
    "#{name}: #{city}"
  end
```

Then use it as below

```
<%= collection_select :player, :team_id, Team.find(:all), :id, :name_with_city, {:prompt => "Select a team"} %>
```

Find out more about `collection_select` in the [documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select)

Answer (score 0):

You can format the collection to your liking as:

```
<%= collection_select :player, 
    :team_id, 
    Team.find(:all).collect { |t| [ t.id, "#{t.name}: #{t.city}" ] },
    :first, 
    :last,  
    { prompt: "Select a team" } %>
```

The `:id` and `:name` parameters have been replaced with `first` and `last` signifying the `value_method` to be `first` and `text_method` to be `last` elements of each array.

Answer (score 0):

If your form is looking up values based on parameters and you need those, the model method is not very convenient. Assuming your controller has a `@searched_record` method, you can do something like

```
<% @base_params = @searched_record.one_value << "=>" << @searched_record.second_value << "; " << (l(@searched_record.starts, :format => :long)) << ", " << @searched_record.other_value.description %>
      <%= f.text_area :content, :rows => 5, value: @base_params %>
```