# Collection_Select display multiple fields in dropdown

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, grouped-collection-select

I'm using collection_select which connects to my Airports model.

**Claim**

```
belongs_to  :departure_airport, :class_name => 'Airport', :foreign_key => 'd_airport_id'
belongs_to  :arrival_airport,   :class_name => 'Airport', :foreign_key => 'a_airport_id'
```

**Airport**

```
has_many :claims
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= collection_select :claim, :d_airport_id, Airport.order('name'), :id, :name, {:prompt => true} %>
```

---

Currently the dropdown displays "Manchester International Airport" (For example) however i would like to include other field names from the same model.

MAN | Manchester International Airport | EGCC (Desired result)

MAN & EGCC are both columns in the Airport model named iata & icao respectfully.

---

I will continue to only save the airport_id however for display purposes that additional information in the dropdown would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add a method to your `Airport` model with the formatted string that you would like display. Something like:

```
def formatted_name
  "#{iata} | #{name} | #{icao}"
end
```

And then pass that method to `collection_select` instead of `:name`. So:

```
<%= collection_select :claim, :d_airport_id, Airport.order('name'), :id, :formatted_name, {:prompt => true} %>
```

See the documentation [here](http://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/4.1.7/ActionView%2FHelpers%2FFormOptionsHelper%3Acollection_select). The argument in question is referred to as the `:text_method`.

Answer (score 0):

The following should help you : [rails 4 -- concatenate fields in collection_select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519540/rails-4-concatenate-fields-in-collection-select)

Basically, you create in your `Airport` model a new method (in `models/Airport.rb`):

```
def collection_select_nice_data
  "#{iata} | #{name} | #{icao}"
end
```

And in `_form.html.erb` you use the newly created `collection_select_nice_data`:

```
<%= collection_select :claim, :d_airport_id, Airport.order('name'), :id, :collection_select_nice_data, {:prompt => true} %>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer and link too. Both answers seem to be pretty identical so i chose the first provided as the accepted answer. Thanks again.